# How to sort by mtime a given list of files in Python3?

Tags: file, sorting, python-3.x, filemtime

I am trying to do a function which receives a list of files (absolute paths) and returns the list sorted by the mtime of the files. Note that the argument is a **list of files**, not a directory path.

Anyone can help me? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
import os

lista = []
path = 'my/custom/path/'
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for file in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(dirname, file))
        lista.append(filepath)
```

This way I get the list (every file in the path and subpaths), now I need to sort it by mtime!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I was only able to manage sorting by mtime if I get a path instead of a list of files (with the function sorted)

Comment: can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of what you've tried so that we can start help you out on something real?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you want is:

```
sorted_list = sorted(lista, key=lambda f: os.stat(f).st_mtime)
```

which will give you the list of files sorted by mtime.

Comment: I tried many different ways, but I failed. That is what I needed, thank you so much!